# AnyLogic Car library: Is there a way of checking if a route exists for a given destination?

Tags: anylogic

I am using AnyLogic car library and have multiple roads and parking lots. However, not every parking slip is accessible from every road. I want to detect this beforehand if the car won't be able to make it to the destination and send them to somewhere else.

Currently when the car enters the `carMoveTo37` block, it throws an error if there is no way of reaching the destination.

[image]

Is there any way of checking this before entering the `carMoveTo` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use the bottom out-port as per the [help](https://anylogic.help/library-reference-guides/road-traffic-library/carmoveto.html#carmoveto):
[image]

So simply reroute those cars via that port or do something else with them :)

Comment: Thank you Benjamin! What confuses me is this explanation: *If a car is set to move to a parking lot, the car will move to the specified parking lot... Cars reserve parking spaces **only when they approach** the parking lot.* But if there is no way of approaching to the parking lot, will it still behave the same?

Comment: Well, try it :)